# Access form's submitted data after (data) transformations have been applied?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller

I need to access in the controller the form's submitted data/fields after all (data transformations) have been applied.

I need to do it because I need to access a transformed data, but using for example `$request->request->get('product')['tags'])`, I get the original submitted data, which is a string instead of an array of `Tag` objects (which is what in my case the data transformer does, i.e. converts a comma separate string of names to an array of `Tag` objects), which is what I need to access in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Through the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` Object, you can only get the raw submitted data which is a string of tag names separated by commas in your case.

The `Data Transformer` of the Form component act on the actual object which in your case is `Product`, so you have to access the Tag objects via the Product object instead.

```
$tags = $product->getTags(); // Collection of Tag objects
```